# Start Screen Issue *To much White Space*

Tags: gui-design, layout, white-space

I am designing a start screen for a tablet application and I don't understand what info I should put into this page. I got my inspiration from 'Envoy', example:

[image: Reference]

But when I showed this off to other, they thought their wasn't enough style and too much whitespace.

I can't find any other application that does this type of view. Does anyone else know? Or know how I can make this design better?

Here is my Design:

[image: My Design]

Comment: Why is the Sign-out button in the Sign-in screen? Could you give a little bit more of detail?

Comment: You can ignore that sign-out button. On my design, the user would have already logged in and this would be the first view they would see.

Comment: So the user comes directly from the log-in page (we assume successfully) and arrives here, but what is the purpose of this screen, why does the user have to tap to load? I'm asking because if we understand the purpose of the page maybe we can give you a better answer.

Comment: The present screen with "Lorem Ipsum" would say "Product Ready to Start", then you would hit the button and then the product would run.

Comment: Why does the user need to load? Can't it just load?

Comment: The button will be "START". Then when you hit the button that says "START", the product will load and then the view will have a progress indicator.

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to have a page that requires the user to press START?  Why not just have the product load on its own?    It sounds like this is just unnecessary busywork for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Without more context it is difficult to tell, but I will try to give some ideas in case they help.

Take a look at how the timer in Android approaches something similar:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the image in the left, they could have simply show the play button and nothing else. However there is the clock which fills part of the screen, giving information of what are we looking at and what will happen in the next step.

If the screen as you shows us already contains all there is to show, then I would try to center everything. This way there are not several empty spaces but just a block of content in the center and the surrounding space. The arrow your button has right now, suggests a drag or swipe. Instead of telling what kind of interaction the user should do, simply tell what action is going to be performed ("Start").

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Give the user an idea of what the application does. The other screenshots work because we know what those applications are. You could use a large background image that shows the benefit of using the app or you could add some text explaining the benefits.

Calm.com, a meditation service, shows users with their imagery and with some short text why they should login. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a background image on the page? This will instantly make it look better. You can also put an icon above the title and maybe a short description (if applicable). If there are any links to stuff like a help forum, also put them here.